# Facebook application username request fql or graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

In one of my facebook applications i need to list the users that i have in my db (width their ids). I need their name, photo, and other details from facebook. Specifically i need to list the top 100 users (considering their points in the app).

I've tested it using fql:

```
$query = "select my top 100 users";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Foreach user

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $total_score = $row['total'];

    $fql = "select name from user where uid=" . $user_id;
    $param  =   array(
        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
        'callback'  => ''
    );

    // Get user names through fql query

    $fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);
    $user_name = $fqlResult[0]['name'];

    // Print user details, photo, name, total score..

}
```

Is the fql way efficient enough?

OR

Another way? Like the graph api:

```
function getName($id) { 

    $facebookUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id; 
    $str = file_get_contents($facebookUrl); 
    $result = json_decode($str); 
    return $result->name; 
}
```

Comment: $query = "select my top 100 users";
??? what kind of funny query is this? @michalis?

Comment: ignore this.. let's say we have our ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do 1 hit to Facebook with FQL using where uid=xx or uid=xx etc and get them all at once.

Also the graph API is the preferred way to communicate with Facebook however you would need to look into it further to see if you could grab details for multiple users at the same time.

Now just thinking further, don't you need to append the access_token to these calls with offline access (which is being depreciated) to get the information.

I am actually thinking a better way to write your entire app would be to capture this information when a user connects to your app and not a bulk process.

Comment: I agree with Adam about caching this information. Also, you can construct the user image URL without an FQL query so there is no need to cache the image URL.

Comment: But what happens if some of the users that are to be listed did't captured yet.?? For example a user sends multiple requests to users, if they accept the request they are captured in the db. But i am also supposed to list and the other users that did't accepted the request yet. Suppose that the user that sends the requests sees a list with all the users that he called.

Comment: Well you are never going to know their details then anyway. You will have to get them to go to the app again. There is only a very limited amount of information you can gain from just a userId, unless you have an access_token to go with it.